# Login function : Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nodemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaP34.png)

I'm trying to login as a user on my website and it's giving me this error, I can register the user and search for it in the login as many times as I want if the password and username are correct, however when there is an error in the user name or password it happens this in postman and even putting the right password and username it does not show the information and stays like this. Only returning to normal when I restart the server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xFbx.png)

I'm a beginner and I'm learning, so I don't know what's wrong, thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Next time, post your code as a snippet in the question, not as a linked picture. Also, if you like my answer please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error generally means that you can not send HTTP headers multiple times.

It occurs when username does not match because in line 24 you send `status(401)` but then code flow continues, trying to send another `status()` later.

It occurs when password does not match because in line 32 you send `status(401)`, code flow continues and then in the next line (34) you try to send `status(201)`. The last call might send you to the exception handler (`catch ..`) in which you also try to send another `status(500)`

to avoid this, you might try:

```
if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json('wrong credentials');
} 

//... get password hash from DB...

if (password !== req.body.password) {
    return res.status(401).json('wrong credentials');
}

return res.status(201).json(user);
```

**Important sidenote:**
You should NEVER encrypt/decrypt passwords.
Store password hashes instead and only ever compare hashes. Use **`bcrypt`**!

Comment: Thank you very much, you are awesome, I managed to solve this problem thanks to you, because you explained it very well, really thank you. And regarding the observation of the encryption I will correct it and use the one you recommended, I had not thought about the security problems that decryption could generate ksksksks, really thank you.